# php mysql pullout text between tags

Tags: php, mysql, regex, substring

I have a wiki database with pages in 'body' in which I have general text including [[GridRef:St12341234]] in. I am trying to create a mysqli statement to pull out just the location info [[Gridref:ST12341234]] or in future [[PostCode:OX1099A]] or [[LATLON:10000,10000]]. So far I have a list of pagenames (tag) with the full page text (body).

```
SELECT tag, body FROM `wikka_pages`  
WHERE body LIKE '%[[GridRef:%'
ORDER BY `wikka_pages`.`tag` ASC
```

However it also includes ALL the other text in body. I cant figure out how to use something like SUBSTRING_INDEX() REGEX or other function to filter the body text. Once the bulk of the text is pulled out I can use php to manipulate it into something to pass to google maps or other. So I am looking to get some output like

```
`| tag | body |
---------------
| Box | GridRef:ST12341234 |
| hill | GridRef:SK12341233 |
| car | PostCode:OX1099 |
-----------------------------`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't extract with a regex in native MySQL. It would probably be easiest to do this in the application with a regex, however it can be done with `locate` and `substring`.

```
SELECT tag, 
substring(body, (locate('[[', body)+2), locate(']]', substring(body, (locate('[[', body)+ 3))))
FROM content
WHERE body LIKE '%[[GridRef:%'
```

The third parameter of `substring` is length we add 3 for the `0` location and the 2 `]]`s.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d43e1/1

If you were to return the full row you then could use something like this in PHP,

```
preg_match('/\[{2}(.+?)\]{2}/', 'sometext[[GridRef:St12341234]]moretext', $match);
print_r($match);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/7TMKf

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/WhalH7/1/

Note if your row has more than one `[[]]` pairing you will need to be more specific with locating the brackets.

Comment: Hi, that looks exactly what I want, however it just causes an error for me. I have tried a really basic version.       $sql = 'SELECT tag, substring(body, 3) and it returns nothing of body?

Comment: What's the error it throws, can you add photos usage to question

Comment: just a generic firefox webpage error, I will need to enable php errors I guess or look in the logs. I have tried;        // Get data from MySQL
     $sql = 'SELECT tag,
        substring(body, 10)
         FROM wikka_pages
        WHERE latest = "Y"
        AND body LIKE "%GridRef%"
        ORDER BY ' . $sql_sort_order . ' DESC
        LIMIT ' . $sql_limit;
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql); However nothing of 'body' is returned,

Comment: ahh - Needs the AS (new name for body); as location then I use $row['location'] ok so, still working on it.

Comment: the body does have lots of [[ and ]] pairs so I need to figure out how to find the ]] after [[GridRef: .... However;      %% substring(body, (locate("[[GridRef:", body)+2), 20) as location %% is giving me something to work with.

Comment: I could just php trim the ]] off, after selecting a max of 12 letters, would that be lazy? lol

Comment: annoyingly rtrim didnt work! but this does; $gridref = strstr($row["gridref"], ']', true);   I have a functional script, Thankyou for your help.

Comment: If there are multiples you are best off just selecting the pull row and using a regex in PHP. Use `preg_match_all` if you want to capture multiple values.